# What is the proper interface for element with "GetWrappedInstance"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writting React+Redux with typescript. I need to access the reference of one wrapped instance, like `this.refs.items.getWrappedInstance()`, but got typescript error `Property 'getWrappedInstance' does not exist on type 'ReactInstance'`
Which interface shall I give to `items`? Are there any interface defined by Redux that I can declare or I need to create my own?
I tried to google and search stackoverflow but cannot find an answer.

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/26871

Answer (score 0):

We got the same error using Flow and our most senior UI developer ultimately said to use // $FlowIgnore: some comment

I think that because accessing wrappedInstance is an antipattern flow and typescript may not support it...yet?

I am interested if anyone has a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and while I didn't find a native solution, I did manage to create one. Below is a working sample implementation with the solution.

Keep note of the `{ withRef: true }` in the `connect` function.

Here is a small utility type to add the missing definition.

```
// connect.ts

type WrappedConnectedComponent<T> = {
  getWrappedInstance(): T
}

export function unwrapConnectedComponent<T>(component: T): T | undefined {
  if (component) {
    const wrappedComponent: WrappedConnectedComponent<T> = component as any

    if (wrappedComponent.getWrappedInstance) {
      return wrappedComponent.getWrappedInstance()
    }
  }

  return undefined
}
```

Here is a simple component that we'll be accessing later.

```
// SomeOtherComponent.tsx

import * as React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class SomeOtherComponent extends React.Component {
  log = () => {
    console.log('logged')
  }

  render() {
    return <div />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => ({})
const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({})

const ConnectedSomeOtherComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  null,
  { withRef: true } // Important
)(SomeOtherComponent)

export default ConnectedSomeOtherComponent

export { SomeOtherComponent }
```

Here is the main component that does all the work.

```
// SomeComponent.tsx

import * as React from 'react'
import ConnectedSomeOtherComponent, { SomeOtherComponent } from './SomeOtherComponent'
import { unwrapConnectedComponent } from './connect'

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  someOtherComponent?: SomeOtherComponent

  private setSomeOtherComponent = (someOtherComponent: SomeOtherComponent) => {
    this.someOtherComponent = unwrapConnectedComponent(someOtherComponent)
  }

  onClick = () => {
    if (this.someOtherComponent) {
      this.someOtherComponent.log()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick} />
        <ConnectedSomeOtherComponent ref={this.setSomeOtherComponent} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SomeComponent
```